# How to estimate how bad the wire delay can be when I am designing a chip?

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

I am currently working on a program involves designing a Neural Network accelerator architecture. I don't have a very deep background in digital circuit, but I know long wires may incur heavy delay and hence affect frequency.

**So how do I know if a long wire may cause problem before I put my design into synthesis and routing?** For example we may have long wires accross 64 PEs in a row, and each PE contains at least one 16-bit multiplier, one adder and some MUXs.

I haven't put our design into routing yet. But I notice that some designs involves these long wires(maybe they never put them to routing), while others try to avoid them. So what should I do as an architecture designer?

Comment: Are you designing a chip? Do you have chip designers working at your company? They should know. You could add delays in long wires so the transfer would take more clock cycles and the clock cycles could be faster.

Comment: You can learn more about static and dynamic timing analysis. Timing closure is accomplished with EDA tools. Any other (manual) approach would be error-prone.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you. But we are just a small research team in university.

Comment: @Syed Thank you. Surely EDA tools will do but redesigning multiple times just costs too much. But I think there should be some experiences or general rules to follow. Like in given technology, a wire of how long incurs about how much delay. Isn't there should be some data tables to checkout?

Comment: What is your hardware implementation platform?

Comment: @Syed TSMC 40nm, for example

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way @RichardCai, but I think you are not familiar (yet) with the design flow for your kit. For a 40nm kit, you definitely need advanced tools.  Your main question is about estimation of resistance. It depends on the capacitance of the layer of metal and that depends on the capacitance to substrate/and to other wires nearby and the dimensions of the wires. Only an extraction tool can do it. There is no scenario for manual calculation here.

Comment: When I work on an FPGA I can just ask for the wire and then the compiler can tell me whether this wire is so long that it's slowing down the timing, then I can add a register in the middle. Although it's not so obvious, because if the compiler thinks things are too slow it will move them closer together and move other things further apart so the problem could appear in the things it moved apart. Agree that knowing the workflow is important. IDK if the FPGA workflow is the same as the real silicon chip workflow.

Comment: @Syed Ok thanks

Comment: @user253751 Ok thanks

Comment: You should ask around if anyone at your university knows what they're doing in chip design. I don't (but I know FPGAs). If this university has a decent sized electronics department, there's quite a good chance someone has designed chips or knows where to look to find expertise about designing chips. I would not expect that knowledge to exist at most companies, but I *would* expect it to exist at a university, with some luck.

Comment: A 2013 paper on NoC, "SMART: A Single-Cycle Reconfigurable NoC for SoC Applications". It says "Our clockless repeater link has been proven in silicon in 45nm SOI. Results show that at 2GHz, we can traverse 8 mm within a single cycle". I mean, this might be of some help.